# How to read file to dataframe in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a problem to write data in Jupyter Notebook. It is csv file and I try to read_csv using Pandas in Python. 
I have error that: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Project Baby Names USA/BabyNamesUSA.csv' does not exist: b'Project Baby Names USA/BabyNamesUSA.csv'` but this file in this folder exists! What should I do ?

But when I use:

```
with open("BabyNamesUSA.csv") as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)

data.head()
```

instead of:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Project Baby Names USA/BabyNamesUSA.csv",
                 usecols=["Name", "Year", "Gender", "Count"])
df.head(5)
```

It works perfect!

Comment: try `pd.read_csv("Project\ Baby\ Names\ USA/BabyNamesUSA.csv",                usecols=["Name", "Year", "Gender", "Count"])`

Comment: Try investigating what `os.path()` can provide. Path-resolution in Jupyter can be weird. I've experienced it starting from the directory I've launched the application from and using the directory of the notebook as the current working directory.

Comment: A few suggestions: (a) see your working directory with `pwd` in a cell. (b) Change working directory with `%cd` when needed. (c) Preferably don't use spaces in names. If you do, you may need to escape them in the manner @vb_rises suggests for shell command but not usually with Python `os.path()` or pathlib objects.